# Swift 3 Unrecognized selector sent to instance UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITouchesEvent text]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6100000e9400'

The button it crashes on:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FBSDKLoginKit

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        // Create Sign Up button
        let signUpButton: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Go Button@1x"), for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(createAccountTapped), for: .touchUpInside) // when tapped on Sign In button, execute function SignInTapped
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return button
            }()
        func signUpButtonView() {
            signUpButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            signUpButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
            signUpButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            signUpButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        }

        self.view.addSubview(signUpButton)
        signUpButtonView()

    }

    func createAccountTapped(_ usernameTextField: UITextField, passwordTextField: UITextField, repeatPasswordTextField: UITextField) {
        let username = usernameTextField.text
        let password = passwordTextField.text
        let repeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text
    }
}
```

I have another button for signing up with Facebook and it works fine... I think it's something to do with parameters in the function `createAccountTapped` but I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: "createAccountTapped" is not IBAction.Which method is connected to button or called on button pressed?...

Comment: @sanman If you read his code you would know that he added a target to his button.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry my bad.I thought Martynas has connected button to that func,which isn't possible.

Comment: @sanman No worries, we all miss stuff ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can not pass `UITextField` instance with `UIButton` action, you can set only these action `createAccountTapped()` and `createAccountTapped(_ sender: UIButton)` with `UIButton`.

If you want to access `textField` in your `UIButton` action then you need to create `IBOutlet` for that `textField` in your `RegisterViewController`.

Comment: How do I pass on constants which I need to use in function then?

Comment: @Martynas You cannot pass other instance instead of `UIButton` with its action. Read my answer once again.

Comment: @Martynas You might want to consider having them as instance variables.