# swift 3 selector with arguments

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I searched a lot for selector method in Swift 3, but I have lots of confusion for it.

1) what is difference between `Selector` & `#selector`?

2) if I write with `Selector`, the function is outlined means not available?

3) How to pass a parameter with `#selector` method.

**My code**

```
let button = UIButton()     
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getData(_:true)), for: .touchUpInside)
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(), for: .touchUpInside)

func getData(_ isShowing:Bool){

    }
```

**Can you help me to clear my confusion?**

**Thank you for your valuable time**

Comment: Compare with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520683/swift-3-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-uibutton

Comment: Regarding question 3. Just use `#selector(getData)` no need to specify the parameters.

Comment: @LeoDabus, Thanks for your answer but I must have to pass a value for checking condition.

Comment: The sender is UIButton, so change the method parameters to `(_ button: UIButton)`

Comment: What you mean to pass a value? You can't pass `true` in the selector

Comment: What is isShowing ? If you need to know if the button is hidden or not just check `if button.isHidden`

Comment: @LeoDabus, no I have different logic on it. isn't there any other option except iVar?

Comment: what you mean different logic? If more than one kind of object calls that method change sender to `(_ sender: Any)`. That's all you can do. Then you can try to cast the object (sender) to the specific type.

Comment: Whats the meaning of passing true ??? it will always be true. Where is true coming from? Whats your goal?

Comment: @LeoDabus, `getData` method called by two different logic. & one with false & one with true.

Comment: You can't have two different actions on the same button. Again you can't pass any parameter in the selector.

Comment: @user1673099 : It seems that you wanted to make a shortcut here, that unfortunatelly is not possible. The best course of action would be to have a separate button handler which would call the `getData` method. Something like this : `func buttonHandler() { self.getData(true) }`

Answer (score 3):

Answers to your questions:

1. **Selector** is a type. (to indicate that it's a function type). Whereas **#selector** is to call a function. `#selector` --> will return `Selector` type. `#selector` checks if there is any function exist with that function name
2. First answer will clarify this
3. You can send value through sender like this. Example: `button.layer.setValue(forKey:"someKey")`

Comment: As to #3 : you can't do that for arbitrary values, only for those compliant with KVO. In regards to what OP wants, he can't pass his `Bool` this way.

Comment: Step #3 worked for me to pass Bool. Swift 5, iOS 13.6

Answer (score 1):

I believe `#selector` is just a language construction that creates an object of type `Selector`. You want to use `#selector` as the compiler actually checks if the method exists anywhere, where with `Selector("abc")` you just run the constructor and it's not validated.